# Server Side - Creating a JSON response

Tags: java, php, json

Attention to all talented coders, First, let me start by saving I have ZERO experience with JSON and not much server side coding experience. Here is what I am trying to do:

I want to build a very simple Backend server in either Java or PHP that responds to a get commands and returns 2 different JSON results based on keyword (i.e. if the keyword starts with A or is blank, return one result. If it starts with B, return a different one). Once again, I have no idea how to go about this and would greatly appreciate if anyone can solve this for me. It's not homework, I'm just trying to learn and pickup some skills. If anyone really enjoys coding and has time to spare, please help me understand how this is done. Any help is greatly appreciated. Really. Thank you all so much in advance.

Here is what I have tried. I ultimately want to send a JSON onbect like below when a keyword is searched.

```
 <?php


    $data = $_GET['keyword'];


      $nullOrA = substr($data, 0)

     if($nullOrA != "A" || "B" || "C"){
    echo "Cannot find anything related to searched Keyword"; 
    }

  if($nullOrA == "A"){
    echo json_encode($candStr); 
}

if($nullOrA == "B"){
    echo json_encode($jobStr); 
}

else if($nullOrA == "C"){
    echo json_encode($companyStr); 
}

//JSON object
 $Response Object:

$candStr = {"candidates": [
        {"lastName":"Doe" , "firstName":"John" , "mailingState":"IN" , "availDate:":"08/15/2013" , "matchPct":"92%", "division":"temps" , "branch":"Branch AA"},
        {"lastName":"Smith" , "firstName":"Lin" , "mailingState":"CA" , "availDate:":"08/15/2013" , "matchPct":"92%", "division":"gloabl" , "branch":"Branch AB"},
        {"lastName":"Memory" , "firstName":"James" , "mailingState":"CA" , "availDate:":"08/15/2013" , "matchPct":"92%", "division":"accountemps" , "branch":"Branch AA"},
        {"lastName":"App" , "firstName":"Tom" , "mailingState":"CA" , "availDate:":"08/15/2013" , "matchPct":"92%", "division":"accountemps" , "branch":"Branch AO"},
        {"lastName":"World" , "firstName":"Yeah" , "mailingState":"CA" , "availDate:":"08/15/2013" , "matchPct":"92%", "division":"accountemps" , "branch":"Branch CA"},
        {"lastName":"Timmy" , "firstName":"Hungry" , "mailingState":"NY" , "availDate:":"08/15/2013" , "matchPct":"92%", "division":"accoun" , "branch":"Branch AA"},
        {"lastName":"Hello" , "firstName":"Luke" , "mailingState":"CA" , "availDate:":"08/15/2013" , "matchPct":"92%", "division":"accountemps" , "branch":"Branch AA"},
        {"lastName":"James" , "firstName":"Ashley" , "mailingState":"CA" , "availDate:":"08/15/2013" , "matchPct":"92%", "division":"accountemps" , "branch":"Branch AD"},
        {"lastName":"Duck" , "firstName":"MAl" , "mailingState":"TN" , "availDate:":"08/15/2013" , "matchPct":"92%", "division":"accountemps" , "branch":"Branch AA"},
    ],
$jobStr ="jobOrders": [
        {"name":"Lawyer" , "company":"DHI" , "availDate":"08/15/2013" , "matchPct":"92%", "division":"Business" , "branch":"Branch NA"},
        {"name":"Accountant" , "company":"HTG" , "availDate":"08/15/2013" , "matchPct":"92%", "division":"accountemps" , "branch":"Branch AA"},
        {"name":"ncurses_addchstr(s)" , "company":"HTB" , "availDate":"08/15/2013" , "matchPct":"92%", "division":"accountemps" , "branch":"Branch OA"},
        {"name":"Accountant" , "company":"KNM" , "availDate":"08/15/2013" , "matchPct":"92%", "division":"global" , "branch":"Branch AA"},
        {"name":"Lead" , "company":"KOL" , "availDate":"08/15/2013" , "matchPct":"92%", "division":"accountemps" , "branch":"Branch AU"},
        {"name":"Accountant" , "company":"KNM" , "availDate":"08/15/2013" , "matchPct":"92%", "division":"accountemps" , "branch":"Branch AA"},
        {"name":"Dev" , "company":"KNM" , "availDate":"08/15/2013" , "matchPct":"92%", "division":"accountemps" , "branch":"Branch CA"},
        {"name":"Accountant" , "company":"KNM" , "availDate":"08/15/2013" , "matchPct":"92%", "division":"Native" , "branch":"Branch AA"},
        {"name":"Analyst" , "company":"KNM" , "availDate":"08/15/2013" , "matchPct":"92%", "division":"accountemps" , "branch":"Branch PO"},
    ],
$companyStr = "companies": [
        {"name":"Fruit" , "mailingState":"IN" , "matchPct":"92%", "division":"temps" , "branch":"Branch RA"},
        {"name":"Insect" , "mailingState":"CA" , "matchPct":"92%", "division":"accountemps" , "branch":"Branch AA"},
        {"name":"Color" , "mailingState":"CA" , "matchPct":"92%", "division":"accountemps" , "branch":"Branch AA"},
        {"name":"Doe" , "mailingState":"CA" , "matchPct":"92%", "division":"account" , "branch":"Branch AA"},
        {"name":"Doe" , "mailingState":"YH" , "matchPct":"92%", "division":"global" , "branch":"Branch AY"},
        {"name":"Doe" , "mailingState":"CA" , "matchPct":"92%", "division":"temps" , "branch":"Branch MN"},
        {"name":"Doe" , "mailingState":"LK" , "matchPct":"92%", "division":"accountemps" , "branch":"Branch AA"},
        {"name":"Doe" , "mailingState":"CA" , "matchPct":"92%", "division":"accountemps" , "branch":"Branch LI"},
        {"name":"Doe" , "mailingState":"BH" , "matchPct":"92%", "division":"account" , "branch":"Branch AA"},
        {"name":"Doe" , "mailingState":"CA" , "matchPct":"92%", "division":"accountemps" , "branch":"Branch AA"},
        {"name":"Doe" , "mailingState":"DV" , "matchPct":"92%", "division":"US" , "branch":"Branch YH"},
    ]
}


?>
```

Comment: JSON is just a format, you don't need "experience with JSON". You should better your backend skills before embarking on something you know so little about, tutorials and books are there for a reason.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you might start with a [very simple php tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/php/)

However, this might get you started:

```
<?php
if ($_GET["keyword"]=="B") {
    echo "a different one!";
} else {
    echo "one result.";
}
```

You should now be able to access `http://yourserver/path/yourphp.php?keyword=A` to get `one result.`, and `http://yourserver/path/yourphp.php?keyword=B` to get `a different one!`